# My Windows 8 computer does not come out of Standby

Tags: windows-8, upgrade, sleep, hibernate, standby

My computer will not come out out of standby. It has had this issue ever since I bought it ~4 years ago. When I purchased it, It came with Vista, I have since upgraded it to 7 and now 8 Pro, each time hoping that it would fix the problem, each time finding that it did not. My computer is an HP Pavilion Model #: m9500y.

The computer goes into standby, but does not come out of it properly. If Hybrid sleep in on, it does not respond at all. If Hybrid sleep is off, It comes out and I can see the desktop for a bit, but then the screen goes black again and I have to reboot.

I have tried Running a sfc, and a chkdsk in case it's a corrupted file, but it hasn't helped. This isn't too serious an issue because I can just shutdown my computer and turn it on the old fashioned way, but it is annoying and I would appreciate some advice going forward as I'm currently stumped.

[image: Power Options]
[image: CPU-Z]
[image: Event Viewer]

Comment: I think that Windows 7 and 8 replaced 'Standby' with Sleep and Hibernate.  Thus my troubleshooting would be to see if it's a sleep or hibernate problem, and then what is the trigger.  PowerCfg at the commandline may help.  Also do the Eventlogs help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you have a look in Eventlog, in particular: 
System Log and filter for 'Kernel-Power' entries.

Another line of research is to look in the device manager and see if there any suspect devices which have a 'Power Management Tab'.

I declare an interest: This is my site, but [troubleshooting Windows 8 sleep problems](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-sleep-mode.htm) is a minor interest of mine.

Comment: The Eventlog mostly just says "enter sleep" and failed to come out of sleep, I'll try inspecting the devices in the device manager in more detail later today.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like a BIOS issue, try changing the sleep states.

Its not always an obvious setting, but it will be a setting (standby mode, or acpi mode) with a value of S1 or S3 typically.

See what options you have and try each.

From Wikipedia article on [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface):

- S1: All processor caches are flushed, and the CPU(s) stops executing instructions. Power to the CPU(s) and RAM is maintained; devices that do not indicate they must remain on may be powered down.
- S2: CPU powered off. Dirty cache is flushed to RAM.
- S3: Commonly referred to as Standby, Sleep, or Suspend to RAM. RAM remains powered
- S4: Hibernation or Suspend to Disk. All content of main memory is saved to non-volatile memory such as a hard drive, and is powered down.

Oh and forgot to mention, have you checked for BIOS updates, as this type of issue is often fixed by them.

Comment: I've gone through all five screens and my BIOS has nothing like this. Maybe it's because it's an old BIOS? I've looked for an update on the phoenix site, but they point me to some utility that has 2 stars on download.com and costs $30. I've looked on the HP website, but they don't have an BIOS drivers listed for my mobo and their support is completely useless. Any suggestions on where I could find a BIOS update for this mobo?

Comment: I've double checked and my BIOS does not have this setting.

Comment: Two other suggestions: Update all drivers, and you could try [link](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00845808&tmp_track_link=ot_faqs/top_issues/en_us/c00845808/loc:12&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=3867529) this HP support page.